# openamq .net library

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a .net client library for openAMQ ?

UPDATE :

Any gotchas/examples of pairing RabbitMQ client with openAMQ Server ? I realize the protocols are different 0.8 / 0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [OpenAMQ languages FAQ](http://www.openamq.org/faq:openamq-languages) :

> There is no native C# client that
>   works with the current OpenAMQ server.
>   RabbitMQ's C# client almost works but
>   the protocol versions are slightly
>   different (0.8 vs. 0.9). It may be
>   possible to make a 0.9 client based on
>   Rabbit Technology's work. Bo Kohut
>   also started a C# wrapper for the
>   OpenAMQ C WireAPI libraries, which is
>   here.

Answer (score 1):

[According to their FAQ](http://www.openamq.org/faq:openamq-languages) there is not, though they propose a partial solution that may involve coding effort on your part.